# IOS JSON parsing gone very messy and bites my tail

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I'm making an app that gets a JSON object from a web server, it's a dictionary with dictionaries.
When I parse this out, I need it all, both as a dictionary and an array, because I need to use both `objectForKey` and `objectAtIndex` to dynamically fill out my TableViews.

Some of it ends up looking like this:

```
NSMutableArray *roomsArray = projectDict[@"rooms"];
NSMutableDictionary *roomDict = roomsArray[indexPath.row];
NSMutableArray *tasksArray = roomDict[@"tasks"];
NSMutableDictionary *task = tasksArray[indexPath.row];
NSString *status =  [task objectForKey:@"status"];
```

Because I need arrays to get `objectAtIndex` with index being `indexPath.row`

But then, when I click my `UISwitch` in my tableview, I need taskStatus to change.

But I can't because it won't "work its way up".

So, I need to:

Grab the TOP dictionary (projectDict) and in 1 line, (without working my way down the arrays and dicts) replace the taskStatus.

This is my projectDict in JSON format printed in the console:

```
projects =     (
            {
        address = "Fugledammen 8";
        city = "S\U00f8borg";
        completedTasks = 0;
        done = 0;
        dueDate = "07/11-2013";
        id = 8;
        rooms =             (
                            {
                id = 9;
                name = Loftet;
                tasks =                     (
                                            {
                        id = 5;
                        name = doSomething;
                        status = 0;
                    }
                );
            },
                            {
                id = 10;
                name = "v\U00e6relse 1";
                tasks =                     (
                                            {
                        id = 6;
                        name = doSomething;
                        status = 0;
                    }
                );
            }
        );
        totalTasks = 2;
        zip = 2860;
    },
            {
        address = "Lygten 37";
        city = "K\U00f8benhavn N";
        completedTasks = 0;
        done = 0;
        dueDate = "06/11-2013";
        id = 6;
        rooms =             (
                            {
                id = 2;
                name = Toilet;
                tasks =                     (
                );
            },
                            {
                id = 3;
                name = Kantine;
                tasks =                     (
                                            {
                        id = 2;
                        name = "S\U00e6tte nyt k\U00f8kken op";
                        status = 0;
                    },
                                            {
                        id = 3;
                        name = "Ops\U00e6tte ny kaffemaskine";
                        status = 0;
                    }
                );
            },
                            {
                id = 4;
                name = "L\U00e6rev\U00e6relse";
                tasks =                     (
                                            {
                        id = 4;
                        name = "Ops\U00e6tte ny tavle";
                        status = 0;
                    }
                );
            }
        );
        totalTasks = 3;
        zip = "";
    },
            {
        address = "Tranedalen 2";
        city = "Ish\U00f8j";
        completedTasks = 0;
        done = 0;
        dueDate = "06/11-2013";
        id = 5;
        rooms =             (
                            {
                id = 1;
                name = "K\U00f8kken";
                tasks =                     (
                );
            },
                            {
                id = 5;
                name = "Badev\U00e6relse";
                tasks =                     (
                );
            },
                            {
                id = 8;
                name = "Sovev\U00e6relse";
                tasks =                     (
                );
            }
        );
        totalTasks = 0;
        zip = 2635;
    },
            {
        address = "L\U00e6rkens Kvt 30c";
        city = Albertslund;
        completedTasks = 1;
        done = 0;
        dueDate = "11/11-2013";
        id = 9;
        rooms =             (
                            {
                id = 11;
                name = "k\U00f8kken";
                tasks =                     (
                                            {
                        id = 7;
                        name = "lav kaffe";
                        status = 1;
                    }
                );
            }
        );
        totalTasks = 1;
        zip = 2620;
    },
            {
        address = "S\U00f8gade 2";
        city = "K\U00f8benhavn K";
        completedTasks = 0;
        done = 0;
        dueDate = "13/11-2013";
        id = 10;
        rooms =             (
        );
        totalTasks = 0;
        zip = 1717;
    }
);
}
```

Comment: You will be a lot happier if you serialize this data into a class and then access / modify its properties.

Comment: Just create classes for each entity.  But I'm a little confused here: since a room contains several tasks, why will they have the save index(indexPath.row)?

Comment: as you might have guessed already, IOS is not my strongest side :p so this was my best solution, but i will look into a more object orientated solution, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
NSMutableArray *roomsArray = projectDict[@"rooms"];
NSMutableDictionary *roomDict = roomsArray[indexPath.row];
NSMutableArray *tasksArray = roomDict[@"tasks"];
NSMutableDictionary *task = tasksArray[indexPath.row];
NSString *status =  [task objectForKey:@"status"];
```

Can be reformatted (no need for Mutable instances just to access items) as:

```
NSArray      *roomsArray = projectDict[@"rooms"];
NSDictionary *roomDict   = roomsArray[indexPath.row];
NSArray      *tasksArray = roomDict[@"tasks"];
NSDictionary *task       = tasksArray[indexPath.row];
NSString     *status     = task[@"status"];
```

Can be consolidated into one line just by appending the indexing as one drills down the structure.:

```
NSString *status = projectDict[@"rooms"][indexPath.row][@"tasks"][indexPath.row][@"status"];
```

Comment: Thanks, that saved me a lot of lines :p but the mutable was just because it crashed when i tried to send a mutable request to an immutable object, but still can't change status bool. so my option now, is to update the boolean on the web server, then go to the previous tableview, activate the seque again, so get the new updated data with the right boolean -.-

Comment: JSON is really just a transport method. One would hope that you have a Room and Task classes and parse the JSON into these classes. The Room class would have a mutable array of task instances. Then the status could be changed in the class. But that is somewhat guessing not knowing what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Zaph I believe that the real issue is that he should be using `indexPath.section` for the index of `roomsArray`, not `indexPath.row`. The other issue is that he didn't specify the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option when he parsed the JSON with `JSONObjectWithData`.

Comment: [projectDict setValue:0 forKey:projectDict[@"rooms"][indexPath.section][@"tasks"][indexPath.row][@"status"]]; that is what i tired

Comment: @Kasper You can create a tracking structure for the JSON with mutable elements but madness is that way. You really need a model class with a mutable array of Room class instances and each Room class has a mutable array of Task instances.

Comment: @KasperSølvstrøm Good, you're using `section` there. Now you only need to make sure you also specify the JSON object to be mutable when you parsed it. So, if using `NSJSONSerialization` to parse it with `JSONObjectWithData`, use the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option.

Comment: @KasperSølvstrøm BTW, don't use `setValue:0`. If it's a string, use `setValue:@"0"`. If it's a `NSNumber`, use `setValue:@0`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [OCTotallyLazy](https://github.com/stuartervine/OCTotallyLazy) and the asArray function. OCTotallyLazy has made my life a lot easier when dealing with json data in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You are using using `indexPath.row` for two completely different (and conflicting) purposes, as the index in the array of rooms, as well as the index in the array of tasks. Is your tableview a list of rooms or a list of tasks? It doesn't makes sense for it to be both (e.g. row 0 is first task for first room, row 1 is second task for second room, etc.). I'm going to assume, below, that you have a different section for each room, and each row is for a separate task.
2. But you've outlined the correct technique for determining the status:

   ```
   NSInteger projectIndex = 0;
   NSInteger roomIndex = indexPath.section;
   NSInteger taskIndex = indexPath.row;

   NSMutableDictionary *projectDict = projects[projectIndex];
   NSMutableArray *roomsArray = projectDict[@"rooms"];
   NSMutableDictionary *roomDict = roomsArray[roomIndex];
   NSMutableArray *tasksArray = roomDict[@"tasks"];
   NSMutableDictionary *task = tasksArray[taskIndex];
   NSString *status = task[@"status"];

   NSLog(@"status = %@", status);
   ```

   and if you want to change that status (and assuming you used the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option when you called `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:...]`, you use the same mechanism outlined above, but this time, just set `status` for `task` to be the string `@"1"`:

   ```
   task[@"status"] = @"1";
   ```

   Or if `status` is a `NSNumber`, it would be:

   ```
   task[@"status"] = @1;
   ```
3. As an aside, your code snippet suggested that you think `status` is a `NSString`. It might be a `NSNumber`. It's a `NSString` if the JSON said:

   ```
   "status" : "0"
   ```

   It's a `NSNumber` if the JSON said:

   ```
   "status" : 0
   ```

   Unfortunately, from your `NSLog`, we can't tell if it's a `NSNumber` or `NSString`. You have to look at the JSON (or look at the `class` of the `status` object in your dictionary. Regardless, you don't want to do `setValue:0` to set this value. Either use `setValue:@"0"` or `setValue:@0` depending upon whether you're dealing with a string or number, respectively.

Now, I don't know how you're determining the index in the `roomsArray` and the index for the `tasksArray` (I'm assuming above that you'll have one section per room, and each row in each section corresponds to the individual tasks), but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Comment: indeed, my rooms are my sections, and each room has a list of tasks.

Comment: So i can hear i serialized my JSON wrong and that is why i can't change the status?

Comment: @KasperSølvstrøm No, the problem is that you're using `indexPath.row` for the room index rather than `indexPath.section`. The fact that you've successfully logged the dictionary tells you that you successfully parsed your JSON. You're just not navigating the nested structure properly.

Comment: But i did get to the right place in my data, and i printed out a "0" and tried to replace it with "1" and it said i couldn't mutate immutable objects :s

Comment: @KasperSølvstrøm It only happened to work (presumably because you tapped the switch in the first row of your tableview). The source of the immutable object error is your failure to specify `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option in the `JSONObjectWithData` call. So there are two problems, (1) not using `indexPath.section` for the index in `roomsArray`; and (2) not specifying `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option in the `JSONObjectWithData` call.